# Error Sqoop import from Couchbase to Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, couchbase, sqoop

On Centos 7, I'm using Couchbase 3.0.1, sqoop-1.4.6.bin__hadoop-2.0.4-alpha, hadoop-2.7.1, couchbase-hadoop-plugin-1.2.0.

I can work with Hadoop and Couchbase independently with no problems, but when I try use the plugin as follows:

```html
sqoop import --connect http://127.0.0.1:8091/ --table DUMP
```

I get the following errors

```html
15/09/21 22:48:03 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
Enter password:
15/09/21 22:48:08 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/09/21 22:48:08 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.1
Note: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/8cfd3c310032067c764d644d36d52b12/DUMP.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
15/09/21 22:48:10 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-hadoop/compile/8cfd3c310032067c764d644d36d52b12/DUMP.jar
15/09/21 22:48:10 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of DUMP
15/09/21 22:48:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address
15/09/21 22:48:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15/09/21 22:48:10 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
15/09/21 22:48:11 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/09/21 22:48:11 WARN util.Jars: No such class couchbase doesn't use a jdbc driver available.
15/09/21 22:48:11 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
15/09/21 22:48:14 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
15/09/21 22:48:14 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Cleaning up the staging area /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1442306591241_0013
15/09/21 22:48:14 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: The bucket password must not be  null.
```

Any idea where I'm going wrong? Or what I can do to find out?

Comment: Your couchbase is asking for a password.